# Cannot initialize QQueue with initializer list

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

A `QList<T>` lets me initialize it with some entries using a initializer list.

Doing the same with a `Queue<T>` gives me a compiler error.

Example code does not compile:

```
QList<qreal> someNumbers { 0.0, 0.1 };
QQueue<qreal> someOtherNumbers { 0.0, 0.1 };
```

Compiler output:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QQueue<double>::QQueue(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
     QQueue<qreal> someOtherNumbers { 0.0, 0.1 };
                                               ^
qqueue.h:49:7: note: candidate: QQueue<double>::QQueue()
 class QQueue : public QList<T>
       ^
qqueue.h:49:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
qqueue.h:49:7: note: candidate: QQueue<double>::QQueue(const QQueue<double>&)
qqueue.h:49:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
qqueue.h:49:7: note: candidate: QQueue<double>::QQueue(QQueue<double>&&)
qqueue.h:49:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Is there some way to initialize a `QQueue<T>` using an initializer list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `QQueue` inherit from `QList`, I found a trick to do that.

```
QQueue<double> *queue;
QList<double> list = {{0.0, 1.1}};
queue = reinterpret_cast<QQueue<double> *>(&list);
qDebug() << queue->isEmpty();
while (!queue->isEmpty()) {
    qDebug() << queue->dequeue();
}
```

however, in this example, list it temporary so if you want to use this outside to the function you will have to use new

Comment: do you think this is actually a bug in qt or the compiler since the constructor should stay the same?

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or not. By reading the source of qqueue, I expected to see a delete of the constructor but that's not the case.

Comment: Do you think it's worth opening a bug at qt's bug tracker?

Comment: I think you can try and see what they will answer. I am curious if they did that on purpose or not.